# jQuery Isn't Updating Span

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I have a function that I'm using on my admin page for a quick icon builder for Fontawesome. When updates are run on the fields, I want it to update the icon within two span boxes (one with a dark and one with a light background).

```js
function buildIcons() {
    let primName = document.getElementById("primName").value;
    let primType = document.getElementById("primType").value;
    
    /* Build Final String */
    let iconString = '<i class="fa-' + primType + ' ' + primName + '"></i>';
    
    /* Insert and Update */
    $('#boxBlack').text(iconString);
    $('#boxWhite').text(iconString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row boxes">
        <div class="child block-white">
            <span id="boxWhite">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-octagon"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="child block-black">
            <span id="boxBlack">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-octagon"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I change the .html to .text, it does update the text of the field correctly... but I can't seem to make it update it so that it is HTML code. Thank you!

Edited to add missing code. Sorry!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: What `<span>` I see no HTML and thus no "span" here.  Please update with the HTML

Comment: All that `if/else` can just be  `type = "fa-"+ primType ;` FWIW OR it can just be removed entirely with `let iconString = '<i class="fa-' + primType + ' ' + primName + '"></i>';`

Comment: Edited to add the additional code and also fixed the if/then (I feel stupid for missing that part, thanks!).

Comment: Right, so, i think it'd be valuable in your case to remove all code that isn't .text and .html, to prove that it in fact is irrelevant to your problem. The only way you could be getting two different results here is if the text that you're inserting isn't what you think it is. .text and .html do what they do, if .html is resulting in an empty span... it's because you're passing something that'd look like an empty span when rendered to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#boxBlack').html(iconString);
$('#boxWhite').html(iconString);
```

```js
  function buildIcons() {
    let primName = document.getElementById("primName").value;
    let primType = document.getElementById("primType").value;
    
    /* Build Final String */
    let iconString = 'Test <i class="fa-' + primType + ' ' + primName + '">' + primName + '</i>';
    
    /* Insert and Update */
    $('#boxBlack').html(iconString);
    $('#boxWhite').html(iconString);
}
buildIcons();
```

```html
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row stuff">
        <input id="primName" value="rocket"/>
        <input id="primType" value="fa-2x"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row boxes">
        <div class="child block-white">
            <span id="boxWhite">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-octagon"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="child block-black">
            <span id="boxBlack">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-octagon"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Holy cow: this did it! The .html I had tried before, but the inclusion of the name within the i tag made the difference. Thank you!